# pyspark expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-mllib

I get the error

> expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector)

by trying this:

I have a function which I convert to a udf for transforming values of a column from a dataframe. Like this:

```py
def func(vector):
   #does something

   return Vector.dense(vector)

udfunc = udf(func, ArrayType(FloatType()))

new_df = df.withColumn("vector",func(df.vector))
new_df.show()
```

The column df.vector has denseVector values.

Has anybody an idea to fix this proplem or a hint ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the part of the you provided the obvious issue is that you declare incorrect return type. Catalyst type of `Vector` is `VectorUDT` not `ArrayType(FloatType())`

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

dummy_udf = udf(lambda _: Vectors.dense([0, 0, 0]), VectorUDT())

sc.parallelize([(Vectors.dense([1, 1, 1]), )]).toDF(["x"]).select(dummy_udf("x"))
```

In Spark 2.0 and later use `pyspark.ml.linalg` to achieve compatibility with `pyspark.ml` API.

Comment: Now it is fixed ! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have one more question @zero323. If I return only a vector 
`return Vector.dense(vector)`
I get the error: 
_TypeError: cannot serialize array([ ...]) of type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>_ 

Which datatype should I use instead ?